# In BigQuery flat-rate pricing, how are the purchased slots shared among different concurrent users?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Suppose that 500 slots have been purchased, user1 launches a BigQuery query that uses all 500 slots. In the middle of the query processing, user2 launches another query that, say, will require 200 slots. The question is basically a scheduling and sharing one: how the slots are to be shared between the users. For instance, will the query from user2 wait for slots to be freed
after the query from user1 finishes, or at least after it requires less slots during processing? Or will the query from user2 grab some slots for its execution even before the query from user1 finishes, and before it requires less slots during its processing, thus effectively suspending/interrupting some execution "threads" for user1 and reallocating the saved slots to user2?

A related question is, regardless of which sharing algorithm in use, whether there is a way to limit a user's ask for the number of slots in his query executions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

About the slot management and dispatch, you have a great description [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/slots). In summary, there is 2 things to know:

- The slot dispatch are calculated on [each query step](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation) (you can see the steps in the query plan, to understand it, the duration of each one and more)
- There is a faire use dispatch of the slots between all the queries.

Therefore, your query2 have just to wait the end of the step in the execution plan before being able to get some slot and start.

About the slot assignments, you can only dispatch the slot on a project, not per users. You can choose the [type of use for the slots](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reservations-intro#assignments)  (QUERY, PIPELINE, ML_EXTERNAL)

Comment: The tips help. Thanks for sharing.